# What does it mean when it asks for the next instance of this program?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures

I have the following program segment:

```
int has8(int* data, int lo, int hi)
{
    int mid;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        mid = (hi + lo)/2;
        if (8 == data[mid])
            return mid;
        if (8 > data[mid])
            lo = mid+1;
        else 
            hi = mid-1;
    }
    return -1;
};
```

The question the asks me this:  `Run the has8 in the next instance: -7 1 2 3 5 7 10 13`

What does this even mean??? I don't even know what it is asking.

Comment: The question is asking you to set `data = [-7,-1,2,3,5,7,10,13]` and an appropriate value for `lo` and `hi` then run through the function one step at a time.